# On windows 10 Education An app is blocked because of system administator settings

Tags: windows, windows-10

My goal is to sync a Samsung 21 with my windows PC and when I removed some bloatware using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChrisTitusTech/win10script/master/win10debloat.ps1) script, I was unable to open the *Your Phone* app, receiving message:

```
This app had been blocked by your system administrator
```

My attempts, without success:

1. Removed the app via the below, downloaded *Your Phone* via the *Microsoft Store*, restarted PC, and launched it (without success)

   ```
   Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.YourPhone* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage
   ```
2. Created a package app [rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hotF.jpg), and restarted PC:

   - *Expected behaviour:* 
      With these 2 attemps getting "Your Phone" working.
   - *Unexpected behaviour:* 
      The app is still blocked by the system administrator
3. Changed `EnableLUA` to `0` in the Registry, then restarted comp:

   ```
   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA
   ```

Comment: Who is the system administrator? Is this a corporate device, or consumer?

Comment: I am the system administrator

Comment: You do understand the script you ran made changes to your system, which is the reason, you are getting that message?

Comment: Then try from the admin account. I'd imagine an education version might be more fussy than regular Home or Pro as to what the standard user can do

Comment: You will have to run the script to revert the changes performed by that particular script if you want to run the "Your Phone" application.

Comment: @Ramhound running the script nor the "restore" script didn't make any change

Comment: [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/media/error-start-store-apps/error-screenshot.jpg) is the message?  [What AppLocker rules have been configured?](https://www.partitionwizard.com/images/uploads/articles/2020/03/app-blocked-by-system-administrator/app-blocked-by-system-administrator-2.png) this will require you to be an administrator be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound  Yes that's the [message](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ktt8meYVVm5P0-Bnjp_fUg7LkLXh8zVV/view?usp=sharing) and the Appocker rules created is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TSLSfkFCEcQcyq8gBFceJPPe2ft4xZWq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Delete the rule.  It shouldn’t exist by default.

Comment: Rule is deleted, restart pc, still having the same issue'

Answer (score 2):

Things like trying to run background apps in Windows blocked by the administrator, or de-bloat scripts like [this](https://git.io/JJ8R4), could cause this error; to resolve this issue with the *Your Phone* app, modify these three Registry keys:

1. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd> → `RegEdit`
2. Modify these keys to the value of `1`:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\EnableMmx
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\EnableCdp
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Messaging\AllowMessageSync
   ```
3. Reboot PC

Comment: I never used that debloat script but this fixed the issue for me

Comment: Could you specify your issue? So I can update my answer

Comment: I'm not sure what triggered it but I was just getting the "This app had been blocked by your system administrator" error for Your Phone